# Show product URL Key with product ID

Tags: magento-1.9, url-key

I'm looking for a way to get the **product URL Key** with the product ID.

Actually, I can get the product URL with this code :

```
$product_id = $_GET["pro"];
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
$my_product_url = $_product->getProductUrl();
```

But I just want the URL Key, not the complete URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get this:

in Collection:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>array(Your_id)))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);


foreach($collection as $col){
  echo $col->getUrlKey();
}
```

In load:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
$my_product_url = $_product->getUrlKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('url_key')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```

It works.

Comment: you can get it even easier. `$_product->getUrlKey()`